# MPI fatal error in MPI_Scatter: 40 bytes received but buffer size is 40

Tags: c, mpi

I have 4 processors and I need to scatter a matrix across all of them.
The matrix has a shape of 8 x 5, every processor shoud have a 2 x 5 chunk of it.

The code:

```
using namespace std;
int main(int* argc, char** argv)
{
    int rank;
    int* batch_a = new int[2 * COLUMN_A];
    int* matrix_a = new int[LINE_A * COLUMN_A];
...
    MPI_Init(argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        cout << "Parent generating data in batch " << i << endl;
        new_line(matrix_a, LINE_A * COLUMN_A);
        new_line(matrix_b, COLUMN_A * COLUMN_B);
    }
        
    cout << "Process " << rank << " is waiting for scatter" << endl;
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(matrix_a, LINE_A * COLUMN_A, MPI_INT, batch_a, COLUMN_A * 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Though after running I have this problem:

```
Process 3 is waiting for scatter
Parent generating data in batch 0
Process 2 is waiting for scatter
Process 1 is waiting for scatter
Process 0 is waiting for scatter
Process 2 gathered a batch of matrix a
Process 1 gathered a batch of matrix a
Process 2 is waiting for broadcast
Process 1 is waiting for broadcast

job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Scatter: Message truncated, error stack:
MPI_Scatter(sbuf=0x000001CB79BB5010, scount=40, MPI_INT, rbuf=0x000001CB79BC4740, rcount=10, MPI_INT, root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
Message truncated; 40 bytes received but buffer size is 40

[1-3] terminated

---- error analysis -----

[0] on DESKTOP-24TO9BK
mpi has detected a fatal error and aborted MPI_Broadcast.exe

---- error analysis -----
```

Am I doing something wrong with MPI_Scatter function? I have no clue.

I have tried to replace hardcoded number of lines of a batch of a matrix a with a const int, didn't work.

Comment: The error message is wrong, which MPI library (vendor and version) are you using.

Comment: I'm using version 10.1.12498.52, which isn't that old

Answer (score 1):

*sendcount* parameter of *MPI_Scatter* is the size of a chunk sent to every process in a communicator, so the value of a *sendcount* parameter should be the same as the size of a *batch_a*.

Comment: A more pragmatic way of seeing it is that if send and receive datatypes are the same, then send and receive counts should also be the same.